# Windows 7 command promt number of buffers and buffer size

Tags: windows-7, command-line, buffer

In Windows 7, the Command Prompt has two configuration options called `Buffer Size` and `Number of Buffers` found in the Options tab. Following these [instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491037.aspx), I've tweaked these two values to increase the amount of history I can see by scrolling. But I'm not sure how exactly are these effecting the command prompt's history. It seems that only the screen buffer size, from the layout tab, has an affect on how much I can scroll. Can anyone explain ? Thanks in advance.